# Random unresponsive mouse + keyboard, sleep + wakeup "fixes" it

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome3

I'm having a frequent issue (sometimes multiple times in a couple minutes) where my keyboard and mouse stops responding. Apparently the system continues operating normally apart from that - normal video display and application behavior, save from mouse and keyboard input.

If I press the desktop button for it to enter "sleep" mode, and then press a key the issue goes away briefly, but after a random amount of time, it happens again.

I've tried disabling all gnome extensions, but it didn't help.

- Hardware:

  - Dell Optiplex 790
  - VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
- OS: Linux Fedora 29 / kernel 5.0.5-200.fc29.x86_64 (I've experienced it on previous kernel versions)
- GNOME Shell 3.30.2

Comment: Have you already tried using a different mouse/keyboard, or plugging your mouse/keyboard into different ports (if available)?

Comment: Hm, good call. I will check and update.